# imagejpeg($img, 'image.jpg', 100); function is working on localhost but not on remote server

Tags: php, gd

`imagejpeg($img, 'image.jpg', 100);` function is working on localhost but not on remote server

I want to save image on remote server but this function is working on local server but not working on remote server. My code is given below

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dest, 'image.jpg', 100);
imagejpeg($dest);
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);`
```

Comment: Is the GD extension installed on the remote server? Have you checked the error log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `echo phpinfo();` to check if GD is enabled in your server. Most probably, it has been disabled. Ask your hosting provider to enable GD or change your hosting service provider. Also turn on error reporting by `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your page to discover any error.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install `GD extension`  on remote server to work on GD functions in PHP.

Please have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php) for the installation procedures.